# pandas read_sql_query is putting header info in first row of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sqlite

I'm using an on-disk SQLite3 database and querying it from my Python code using the sqlite3 package. In addition, I'm using pandas to run the query and return the query results as a DataFrame that can be printed nicely, explored easily, etc. Here is my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name) # @UndefinedVariable

results_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM nodes_tags LIMIT 10;", conn)    
print(results_df)

conn.close()
```

For some reason (and only for some of my database tables, not all of them), the DataFrame I'm getting back includes the column headers as the first row of data, like this:

```
         id     key             value     type
0        id     key             value     type
1  75411942  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
2  75411946  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? These SQLite3 tables were generated using data imported from CSV files (one per table). When I run `head table_name.csv` in the terminal, the headers of tables that don't return the extra row when queried and the headers of tables that do return the extra row look similarly formatted, so I don't think the source header data is to blame (probably).

****EDIT****

Also, I just looked at the beginning of the tables in the sqlite3 environment, and the first row for the problem tables there is also a repeat of the header info, but I'm still not sure how that happened.

The code that I used to create the original CSV files is:

```
nodes_tags = []
nodes_tags.append([id_value, key_value, value_value, type_value])
#Does this many, many times

#for data = nodes_tags, nodes_tags is a list of lists
nodes_tags_df = pd.DataFrame(data = nodes_tags,
                             columns=['id', 'key', 'value', 'type'])
nodes_tags_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
nodes_tags_df.to_csv('../CSV for SQL Tables/nodes_tags.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Please post a code where you're writing/saving DF into SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. In the end, it turns out that the problem was with my SQLite3 import of the CSV files themselves. Apparently, since I had already constructed the tables (including column header titles), the import from the CSV file interpreted the header row as a data row. It didn't do that for a few of the tables because the schema disallowed the data type needed for the header titles to be inserted as data and thus, for those, the header row was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_sql_query()` couldn't add this extra row - it's in the SQLite DB table.

So you would need to check how and what are you writing to SQLite DB.

Most probably you've used `header=None` argument when you parsed your CSV file(s).

Demo:

```
In [56]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)

In [57]: df
Out[57]:
          0       1                 2        3
0        id     key             value     type
1  75411942  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
2  75411946  source  tiger:boundaries  regular

In [58]: df.columns = ['id', 'key', 'value', 'type']

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
         id     key             value     type
0        id     key             value     type
1  75411942  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
2  75411946  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
```

Workaround:

```
In [60]: df = pd.read_csv(filename)

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
         id     key             value     type
0  75411942  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
1  75411946  source  tiger:boundaries  regular
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's it. I"ve posted the code for creating the CSV files in the original post as an edit. `header = None` was never used. However, I noticed that, when generating the `nodes_tags` list of lists to put into the DataFrame before doing `DataFrame.to_csv()` I only explicitly added a nested list to the tables that are working correctly now when I query them. The headers for the others are provided solely by the DataFrame header definition. Perhaps that did it? I'll give it a try and see if anything improves.

Comment: Whoops, no sorry, I just looked again and misspoke. None of the lists of lists had an explicit header row added at any time. The headers were all provided when they instantiated their respective DataFrames. So that isn't it. Other thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify, I never parsed the CSV files with pandas, I actually created them with pandas, then passed the CSV files as tables to sqlite3 through the terminal using `.mode csv .import nodes_tags.csv nodes_tags`

Comment: @emigre459, well I thought that you parsed your DF from a CSV file.... I'm pretty sure that the problem occured in the DataFrame __before__ you've written it to SQLite DB table... So check the code which generates your DF just before you're writing/saving it to SQLite DB...